# How to convert the Ipython kernel on kaggle to pdf and download it?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pdf-generation, file-conversion, kaggle

I want to download all the simulation with code and respective output in a .pdf file. Is there any way that it can be possible?

I'have tried downloading the Ipython notebook and opening it on my PC in jupyter notebook and then converting it to pdf. But I'm searching for the direct way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### TL;DR

As of now, downloading the jupyter notebook and then converting it to PDF is the quickest way.

---

If you still wish to convert the notebook to PDF on kaggle itself, you can do it using command line by following these steps:

*Note that the Internet should be connected (check from the right menu).*

**1.** Ensure all necessary libraries are installed.

```
!pip install nbconvert  # already-installed (most probably)
!apt install pandoc  # already-installed
!apt install texlive-xetex -y  # this'll take a long time
```

**2.** Use [`nbconvert`](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) to convert jupyter notebook to PDF

```
!ls  # will output notebook name e.g. `__notebook_source__.ipynb`

!jupyter nbconvert --execute --to pdf __notebook_source__.ipynb
```

**3.** Now, either you can *Commit and Run* *(see Edit below)* and get this file on *Output* tab or simply upload it using SSH or third-party service like [transfer.sh](https://transfer.sh/) *(Use [file.io](https://www.file.io/), transfer.sh doesn't work anymore)*.

```
#!curl --upload-file __notebook_source__.pdf https://transfer.sh/notebook.pdf
!curl -F "file=@__notebook_source__.pdf" https://file.io
```

This will output a url like this:
`https://file.io/uYWP0azE2soj` Go to the url and get your file.

---

Note that you can skip installing `texlive-xetex` if you only want HTML file.

---

**Edit:** It turns out Kaggle has changed it GUI a little bit, so, if you're Commiting and Running by clicking on `Save Version` and you're doing a `Quick Save`, then you need to select `Save output for this version` in Advanced Settings in order to save output pdf file. Or you can simply use `Save & Run All (Commit)`, it'll save output pdf as well.

Comment: The name is `__notebook_source__.pdf`, not `notebook_source.pdf`. Use `!ls` to list files. See edit as well.